# How do you conda install a library in an environment created with virtualenv?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, conda

I'm working on a (python) project where the choice was to create a virtual environment using virtualenv. However, one of the project dependencies can't be installed through pip on macOS due to this bug: https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/283

The workaround is to conda install one of the dependencies to bypass the gcc compiler.

How do you conda install something in a virtual environment not created with conda?

Comment: Is it possible to just create a conda env?

Comment: Either use conda env if you really need conda or just use pip to install binary version (precompiled).

Comment: Yes, thank you. Your answer is good, but the root of all evils is some frozen project documentation that guides the installation using virtualenv. If we could use conda we'd use your answer. Given that this is a challenge across the team we will probably move to using docker containers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think the easiest approach would be to create a conda env by it's own.

1) Create a requirement.txt file by doing `pip freeze > requirements.txt` inside your virtualenv environment

2) Create conda env: `conda create --name myenv`

3) Activate your environment: `source activate myenv`

4) Install your dependencies: `conda install --file requirements.txt`

5) Install missing dependecy: `conda install YOUR_MISSING_DEPENDENCY`

Comment: Is there a way to use that `--file` against a `requirements.txt` **AND** install (fallback to) PyPi if some package is not found in conda channels? Does conda have a channel that mirrors PyPi?

EDIT: Hmm, maybe it's not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57127963/457116

Answer (score 0):

In the accepted answer (upvoted) you can also change point 1) to use `conda`-installed packages (compatible with `subsequent conda install`, and excluding `pip`-installed packages that would be unavailable in `conda` channels, identified by "pypi" in their extended version names that only `conda` displays):

```
conda list --export | grep -v pypi > requirements.txt
```

And if you still want to use `pip`, the correct syntax that gets you packages versions list in a format compatible with `pip install` is now:

```
pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt
```